# Post Type Order not working when applied filter

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using this Post Type Order [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/) 
It's working well as ajax drag and drop things in Wp-admin custom post listing, but not reordering when we filtered posts by category. For example, It's working for

https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=schools

But not worked for if we applied a category filter in the posts list.

https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=schools&action=-1&m=0&schools_category=nyc&seo_filter&readability_filter&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1

It should be work same drag and drop custom reorder posts for above both conditions.

Can you please help me, anyone. Or any other suggestions.

Here is the Js code from the plugin files

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) 
    {
        var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
            sParameterName,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    };

jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {

        jQuery('table.posts #the-list').sortable({
                                                    'items': 'tr',
                                                    'axis': 'y',
                                                    'update' : function(e, ui) {

                                                        var post_type           =   jQuery('input[name="post_type"]').val();
                                                        var order               =   jQuery('#the-list').sortable('serialize');

                                                        var paged       =   getUrlParameter('paged');
                                                        if(typeof paged === 'undefined')
                                                            paged   =   1;

                                                        var queryString = { "action": "update-custom-type-order-archive", "post_type" : post_type, "order" : order ,"paged": paged, "archive_sort_nonce"    :   CPTO.archive_sort_nonce};
                                                        //send the data through ajax
                                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                                          type: 'POST',
                                                          url: ajaxurl,
                                                          data: queryString,
                                                          cache: false,
                                                          dataType: "html",
                                                          success: function(data){

                                                          },
                                                          error: function(html){

                                                              }
                                                        });

                                                    }
                                                });


});
```

Answer (score 3):

This plugin worked with all filters and you can use your custom drag and drop re-order of the post in the custom post type.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-custom-post-order/